# Launch linux app using PHP (Apache) with root privileges for certain commands

Tags: php, linux, apache, node.js

I am running several instance of Node and all of them run on different ports.

I need a way to be able to kill a particular instance of Node based on the port it is running (kill node instance binded to port n).

From my terminal I can easily do a "fuser -k xxxx/tcp" xxxx being the port.

The thing is, that is because I have the authorisation to do so. My question is: I want to be able to have a PHP file that closes the node instance running on port n and it can be opened by anyone. How to do this without opening huge security holes?

Thank you!

Comment: could have php simply execute an external binary that does this, either making that binary suid (bad idea) or calling sudo to elevate the shell this external app is running in.

Comment: Can you tell me why that instance needs ROOT privileges? Always a bad idea, better would be to give a certain user enough permissions to complete that task, and start that node with that user...

Comment: I've done something similar at my company for managing CRON jobs. In order to not allow people to directly call a script that kills another. The interface people uses only sets a flag in the database, which then the "Reaper" or the killing script can come along and kill off. In this way, the interface can be on a completely different web server.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. 
John, it's that "fuser" won't work unless the user has the necessary auth. That's why I can execute it using my terminal but apache can't when running the PHP script that can be launched by anyone.

Comment: Cillosis, thanks! Sorry I'm not very familiar with Linux. In what database does your interface change a flag?

Comment: Also, if there's a way to get the PID without any extra auth of aa process running on a certain port that'd be good as I could simply call "kill" with the PID afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider adding one more endpoint to your server, such as `/shutdown`, that would call `process.exit()`;

Result is immediate, easier to implement than using a bunch of shell commands, tracking pids, etc...

Also easy to protect via password, signed request, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Just saw this. I did somewhat similar earlier today.

I added an interval inside the node server I want to close that periodically sees if a file with a specific file name exists in its own directory. If so, it quits.
The said file is created easily by PHP without needing any auth.
There it is, solved.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to have php write the port number to a file, then have a cron script run as root (or whatever user it needs to be) and read the port number(s) from that file.  The cron script should have some sort of safety measures in there as well, such as not stopping whatever is running on port 80 or not a node process at all.

edit: for a bit more security, you could require the port number to be prefixed by a "password" that would require you to input.  Then the cron script would verify it's prefixed by that password (or hash it and compare the hash would be even better)

Comment: A cron script run every X seconds?
Can cron jobs run as soon as a file is modified? It really has to be almost real time (absolutely less than a minute).
Thanks!

Comment: @rockamic well you could make the script run once a minute but have the script loop say 4 times with a 15 second sleep so that it runs once every 15 seconds.  In actuality you'd want it to run something like 4 times with a 13 second sleep to prevent the the script from possibly not ending before the next one starts.

Comment: Thanks Eric. What I ended up doing since I'm not the sysadmin and it would be way too complicated for us to do so since this program will be deployed inside some institutions and it would imply messing with their internal configs was the following (thank you for your idea):
 added an interval inside the node server I want to close that periodically sees if a file with a specific file name exists in its own directory. If so, it quits. The said file is created easily by PHP without needing any auth. There it is, solved.